# What does the mean of "at medical facilities"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the mean of at?

> Japan's government will quarantine all people arriving from China and South Korea for two weeks at medical facilities as part of its quarantine law.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask *What does 'at medical facilities' mean?*

It means establishments where medical work is carried out. The travellers will be quarantined in hospitals or clinics, not in hotels or at home.